# Google Earth plug-in: how to get name/description of a model, from lat/long or click

Tags: google-earth

In Google Earth, if you move the mouse over a 3D model (building), it
turns light blue. If you click on it, you get a description (or
sometimes just an approximate address).

Google Earth plug-in web apps like Monster Milktruck or [First Person Cam](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/firstpersoncam/index.html)
are wonderful educational tools for
exploring an area, and learning about it spatially. For example you
are walking or driving around Rome, and you see buildings like the
Coliseum or the Forum, but you don't know what they are; so it would
be very useful to be able to click on them as you can in Google Earth,
and get a description.

Is there any way to do this in the G Earth Plug-in API? I see that a
[hitTest](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/hittest.html) can tell you whether you clicked on a model, and if so, what
the lat/lon of your hit is. But surprisingly, it doesn't tell us
*which* model was hit. Nor can I find any way to look up the model in
Google 3D Warehouse using the lat/lon.

Can someone tell me a way to do this?
Or is it for sure not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you can do this but a way around the problem would be to add placemarks as labels by objects which could be clicked to find out what an object is.  It wouldn't be as elegant as the blue rollover behaviour (lots of placemarks hanging about cluttering the view and making rendering more complex) but it would work.

Comment: That's an interesting approach... How would I know what labels to put where? Essentially I'd be duplicating the whole Google 3D Warehouse, except replacing 3D shapes with points, right? Or is there some way to query the warehouse to find out what models are in a particular area?

Comment: I was assuming you were creating fresh content to behave like the warehouse buildings.  If you want to use the actual data, as you point out, things get complex very quickly.